# How to grep a data within a square brackets?

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression

I have following type of data in my .log file:

```
Cell[BoxData["0.8693473380926441`"]
Cell[BoxData["100.40266203596555`"]
Cell[BoxData["23.338724857049048`"]
Cell[BoxData["0.25720321805387686`"]
Cell[BoxData["66.85236878385265`"]
```

I want to grep only the numeric numbers, like:

```
0.8693473380926441
100.40266203596555
23.338724857049048
0.25720321805387686
66.85236878385265
```

I have tried, `grep -Po '\[.*?]'`, but it only eliminates one brackets.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` is better for this:

```
awk -F '["`]' '{print $2}' file
```

That sets the field separator as either `"` or a tilde and then prints the second column/field.

Output:

```
0.8693473380926441
100.40266203596555
23.338724857049048
0.25720321805387686
66.85236878385265
```

Comment: Its perfect, Thank you very much

Comment: @AmanullahMalik. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below mentioned command and worked fine

```
 sed 's/.*\["//g' filename| sed 's/`"\]//g'
```

output

```
0.8693473380926441
100.40266203596555
23.338724857049048
0.25720321805387686
66.85236878385265
```

Comment: If you're going to use `sed` for this then you don't need to call it twice. You can use `-e` for multiple statements.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance anyone can answer the question in the subject instead of the example. I am trying to use awk to grab the number in “[nnn]” and while `awk -F'\[' '{print $2}' | awk -F'\]' '{print $1}’` works, it sure seem ugly. I have tried `-F’[[]]’` and `-F’[\[\]]’` but neither work

Answer (score 0):

grep for what it is you actually want.  What you want from that is just the numbers.  You want some digits, and a period, and some digits, so:

```
egrep  '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' -o foo.txt
```

The `-o` says "Only print the part that matches, not the entire line".